# How to create hover around Png image itself in css

Tags: css, html

I want to create a hover around png image itself, but i get hover around the entire grid. Ana help would be highly appreciated. i just want that shade around the android png image only.

```css
.button1 {
    border: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    font-size: 16px;
    
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}


.button3:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body>
    <div class="grid">
           
 <button id="btnMakeCall" class ="button1 button3">
<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/android_logo/android_logo_PNG34.png" style="width:80%; height:auto;" />

 </button>

   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.button3:hover img {...}`

Comment: Think you would need to convert it to an svg then you can apply a drop shadow to it here is an example or 2: [codepen](https://codepen.io/adamaoc/pen/PwevMj), [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2c6nkqbr/)

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jXNydE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to achieve this through the use of a standard PNG file. The Android logo may have a transparent background but it still has dimensions that make it a quadrilateral in shape (This is why your image - on hover - shows the dropshadow behind your button). You can get the desired result by doing what @Pete recommended or creating an [image sprite](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).

[Example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sprites_hover_nav)

Comment: Thanks @Peter.  thats what i was looking for image sprite